# How to delete all the HTML body elements except some specific elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a list of HTML files in a folder.
I fetched all the HTML files from the folder and for each html page using jsoup I get the HTML document element.

Now i have to delete all the Html body elements except two div elements from each HTML page. 
How do I achieve that?

Comment: How many files are you talking about? Size? Are you putting them in memory at the same time? This seems like the job for an stream. Parallel. I was going to suggest SAX but it doesn't make sense. The lambda expression it would get convoluted... – efekctive 23 mins ago

Comment: I need to know how to remove all the body elements from HTML except 2 div elements. How can I do that in jsoup?

Comment: Ok. give me a sec.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the html and what specifically you need to save/delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution may look something like this:

```
Elements bodyChildElements = doc.body().children();

for(Element e : bodyChildElements){
    if(!e.tagName().equals("div")){ 
        e.remove();
    }
    else if(!e.attr("id").equals("abc") && !e.attr("id").equals("xyz")){
        e.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

This will grab all of the elements underneath body and remove them from the document unless they are divs with the specific id attribute values.

Comment: thanks justin. I was looking for the same.but I should keep only 2 div elements which has <div  id="xyz">...... <\div> and <div id="abc">...... <\div> and I should delete rest all the elements from the body.

Comment: @LazyGuy I updated the answer to reflect the specific divs you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode/comments

`Jsoup.parse(File in, String charsetName, String baseUri)` will generate a Document.

`Document.body()` should give you the body of the html file.

then you could use (in Jsoup package)

```
public static String clean(String bodyHtml,
                           String baseUri,
                           Whitelist whitelist,
                           Document.OutputSettings outputSettings)
```

to do it in a call or use any of the search functions (getElementBy) and output the result in anyway you want.

You can get fancy an put the list in a stream or parallel processing with runnables to keep control of the process